# Using a bluetooth headset with aux support on a PC

Tags: microphone, headphones, computer, windows-10, headphone

I recently got a headset(Boat Rockerz 510). 
Its a bluetooth headset and has AUX support so that's how i use it majority of the time on my PC. 
I really need to get the mic working on the PC, so i got a splitter and used that to connect it to the mic in and audio in ports on my PC. However, this does not work, all i get is a buzz when i listen to the mic input using settings.

The mic works perfectly while i am using bluetooth on the phone so the mic isn't broken. The aux cable I am using has 2 sleeves on it. I'm also wondering if i should be using an aux cable with 3 sleeves. I've looked around locally for it and could not find one so i couldn't test it. I could just look for it online but, I've already bought 2 different splitters and aux cables so i just want to be sure before i make another purchase that it will work, if someone could give me an idea on what i need to purchase or configure to get my mic working on the PC, that would be awesome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need a cable that has four connections. Ground, L, R and mic. This will need to split to two connectors - one stereo connector and one connector for the mic as usually, on PC's the mic connector is seperate.

IF you can, try and find a way of using the bluetooth interface for everything - that will give you a better chance of making it work.

Comment: I have a splitter at home that i bought before. Can you tell me the name of the cable i need to buy? Online i found a 3 ring male to two female cable, could i just use 2 x 2 ring aux cables male to male along with that to get it working? Or would i be better off with a 3 ring male to male and use my splitter with it?

Comment: looks like the cable from the boat rockerz 510 pictures does not support a mic connection at all. Only three conductors on the connector in the picture. You will have to use bluetooth to get access to the mic.

Answer (score -1):

I too had the same problem with my Rockerz 550. I was having a hard time in solving it but finally I got a really simple solution for it. I first connected the headphones via aux. Then went to the REALTEK AUDIO CONSOLE, from there to DEVICE ADVANCED SETTING and then in the CONNECTOR RETASKING I selected the analog as HEADPHONES instead of speaker out.

This enabled my headphones to work both as mic and audio out. At least it worked for me.